# Reduced Survey Frequency - Salesforce Workflow

Tags: salesforce

Hoping you can help me review the logic below for errors. I am looking to create a workflow that will send a survey out to end users on a reduced frequency. Basically, it will check the Account object of the Case for a field, 'Reduced Survey Frequency', which contains a # and will not send a survey until that # of days has passed since the last date set on the Contact field 'Last Survey Date'. Please review the code and let me know any recommended changes!

```
AND( OR(ISPICKVAL(Status,"Closed"), ISPICKVAL(Status,"PM Sent")), 
OR(CONTAINS(RecordType.Name,"Portal Case"),CONTAINS(RecordType.Name,"Standard Case"), 
CONTAINS(RecordType.Name,"Portal Closed"), 
CONTAINS(RecordType.Name,"Standard Closed")), 
NOT( Don_t_sent_survey__c ) 
, 
OR(((TODAY()- Contact.Last_Survey_Date__c) >= Account.Reduced_Survey_Frequency__c ),Account.Reduced_Survey_Frequency__c==0, 
ISBLANK(Account.Reduced_Survey_Frequency__c), 
ISBLANK(Contact.Last_Survey_Date__c) 
))
```

Thanks,
Brian H.

Comment: Any help here would be great! Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the syntax where `&&` and `||` are used instead of `AND(), OR()`functions. It just reads bit nicer to me, no need to trace so many commas, keep track of indentation in the more complex logic... But if you're more used to this Excel-like flow - go for it. In the end it has to be readable for YOU.

Also I'd consider reordering this a bit - simple checks, most likely to fail first.

**The first part - irrelevant to your question**

Don't use `RecordType.Name` because these Names can be translated to say French and it will screw your logic up for users who will select non-English as their preferred language. Use `RecordType.DeveloperName`, it's safer.

`CONTAINS` - do you really have so many record types that share this part in their name? What's wrong with normal `=` comparison? You could check if the formula would be more readable with `CASE()` statement. Or maybe flip the logic if there are say 6 rec types and you've explicitly listed 4 (this might have to be reviewed though when you add new rec. type). If you find yourself copy-pasting this block of 4 checks frequently - consider making a helper formula field with it...

**The second part**

`ISBLANK` checks could be skipped if you'll properly use the "treat nulls as blanks / as zeroes" setting at the bottom of formula editor. Because you're making check like

```
OR(..., 
    Account.Reduced_Survey_Frequency__c==0,
    ISBLANK(Account.Reduced_Survey_Frequency__c),
    ...
)
```

which is essentially what this thing was designed for. I'd flip it to "treat nulls as zeroes" (but that means the `ISBLANK` check will never "fire"). If you're not comfortable with that - you can also "safely compare or substract" by using

```
BLANKVALUE(Account.Reduced_Survey_Frequency__c,0)
```

Which will have the similar "treat null as zero" effect but only in this one place.

---

So... I'd end up with something like this:

```
(ISPICKVAL(Status,'Closed') || ISPICKVAL(Status, 'PM Sent')) &&
(RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Portal_Case' ||
 RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Standard_Case' ||
 RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Portal_Closed' ||
 RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Standard_Closed'
) &&
NOT(Don_t_sent_survey__c) &&
(Contact.Last_Survey_Date__c + Account.Reduced_Survey_Frequency__c < TODAY())
```

No promises though ;)

---

You can easily test them by enabling debug logs. You'll see there the workflow formula together with values that are used to evaluate it.

Another option is to make a temporary formula field with same logic and observe (in a report?) where it goes true/false for mass spot check.